# C++ CGI execution/processing halts if I do not regularly cout or cerr

Tags: c++, cgi, buffer

I am using a **c++** `CGI program` which is being called through a `PHP curl` call (I have also run this same c++ cgi program from the direct cgi link).
The program works fine but every so often I find that the execution of the program halts (even for the same data set). However, if I send data to `cout/cerr` then the execution continues as normal.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

System Information:

- **OS** : `Ubuntu 11.10`
- **Server** : `Apache2`
- **DB** : `MySQL 5.1.62`
- **C++ Compiler** : `gcc`

Comment: How long of delay is there before the CGI program writes anything?  Apache might kill it if the delay is too large.

Comment: Hi Corbin, I tried it on a small set of data about 100 records. The execution takes about 5 seconds to complete if it doesn't stop in between. Do you know about any directive in Apache which may control this?

Comment: @Corbin I checked the apache2.conf file and the TimeOut is set to 300 seconds